# document library ribbon greyed out

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

In a document Library from Files New Document/Upload Document/New Folder/Edit Document/Library Setting have been greyed out for all web application/ sites. I have admin rights with Full Control and checked with all browsers (run as administrator)

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: hard to guess what's wrong if you don't provide more details (template of the site, customization (through dev or not), version of sharepoint, any error message in the javascript console of the ULS log viewer, ....)

Comment: Thanks Steve. I am new to Sharepoint. I am using Sharepoint 2013. There is no error, just few of ribbon greyed out after a server restart. v4master file HTML incompatibility error.Can you please advise which file should i check for errors? The same for all website for all sites.